# How to move the input element to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I try to move input of newsletter sign-up form to the bottom of the website. It currently covers the inscription newsletter. I used all possible ways to resolve it. I will be grateful for any suggestions that can remove this problem.

```css
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .form-group {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: -20px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 0;
      -ms-border-radius: 0;
      border-radius: 0; 
}
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .form-group input {
      padding-right: 40px;
      background: #fff !important;
      border: 1px solid #ece4d5 !important;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
      font-size: 14px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 0;
      -ms-border-radius: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
}
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .form-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .form-group input::-moz-placeholder {
      /* Firefox 19+ */
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important; 
}
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .form-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* IE 10+ */
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important; 
}
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .form-group input:-moz-placeholder {
      /* Firefox 18- */
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important; 
}
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .form-group .form-control {
      border: 1px solid rgba(100, 255, 255, 0.2);
      font-weight: 400;
      bottom: 20px;
}
 
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .icon {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 10px;
      color: black;
      bottom: 20px;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
#colorlib-aside .colorlib-footer .colorlib-subscribe-form .icon .btn-info{
      color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorlib-footer"> 
  <h3>Newsletter</h3>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> 
    <form action="action.php" class="colorlib-subscribe-form"> 
      <div class="form-group d-flex"> 
        <div class="icon">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
            <span class="icon-paper-plane"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address"> 
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hSc0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control GameO7er" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
```

at the start of file before `<body>` and after `</head>` add this :

```
...
</head>
<style>
.GameO7er{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
...
```

In your case you change your code to this :

```
<div class="colorlib-footer " style="bottom: 0px;">
```

Comment: No elements are allowed between `</body>` and `</html>`. `<style>`s go in the `<head>`.

Answer (score -1):

If you could post the html of the whole page that would be more helpful. The quick answer though is that you would want to copy that html snippet and then paste is below whatever element you wanted it sitting under.